# Setting up Word Diff in Git

Tags: git, github

I'm extremely new to git/github and I don't understand the instructions under the setup section for Word Diff (https://github.com/benbalter/word_diff). I've already created a bot account and a personal access token in my normal account. But after that point I have no idea what he's talking about, can anyone help?

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to run this particular tool?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand his instructions about setting the keys, etc. so that my bot account can automatically convert the .doc file to .md.